# How to replace string to let youtube be written in new share code?

Tags: php, youtube

Not a programmer, just a forum admin so any direct answer will be much appreciated as I know it's a simple answer.

I have an outdated forum mod to embed youtube videos.  Youtube changed their share link and I don't know how to update this so that people can post both the old format with www.youtube.com/watch?=v(location) and the new format that looks like youtu.be/(location)

```
$passiveVid[] = array (
    'string' => '#'.$urlrx[0].'(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\.)?youtube.com/(?:watch)?\?v=(.{11}?)'.$urlrx[1].'#',
    'replacement' => '$PASSIVEURL = $matches[1]; $PASSIVETITLE = $matches[3]; $PASSIVEEMBED = \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\'; return "'.$customstring.'";',
    'id' => 1
    );
$passiveVid[] = array (
    'string' => '#\[youtube\]([^\[\]]+)\[/youtube\]#',
    'replacement' => 'return \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\';',
    'id' => 1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not really an expert on regexes, this should probably work:

```
$passiveVid[] = array(
    'string' => '#' . $urlrx[0] . '(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\.)?youtube.com/(?:watch)?\?v=(.{11}?)' . $urlrx[1] . '#',
    'replacement' => '$PASSIVEURL = $matches[1]; $PASSIVETITLE = $matches[3]; $PASSIVEEMBED = \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\'; return "' . $customstring . '";',
    'id' => 1
);
$passiveVid[] = array(
    'string' => '#\[youtube\]([^\[\]]+)\[/youtube\]#',
    'replacement' => 'return \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\';',
    'id' => 1
);
$passiveVid[] = array(
    'string' => '#' . $urlrx[0] . '(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\.)?youtu.be/(.{11}?)' . $urlrx[1] . '#',
    'replacement' => '$PASSIVEURL = $matches[1]; $PASSIVETITLE = $matches[3]; $PASSIVEEMBED = \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[2].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\'; return "' . $customstring . '";',
    'id' => 1
);
$passiveVid[] = array(
    'string' => '#\[youtu\]([^\[\]]+)\[/youtu\]#',
    'replacement' => 'return \'<object width="712" height="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\'.$matches[1].\'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="712" height="400"></embed></object>\';',
    'id' => 1
);
```

Otherwise you could also do this:

```
$newString = str_replace('youtu.be/', 'youtube.com/watch?v=', $originalString);
```

Above your other code, which is a tad more easier than f-ing with regexes :).

Comment: Thank you!  The long one worked, the short one didn't.  Where was the short one supposed to be placed, as first line?

Comment: Above the two other new array's. But it isn't a copy/paste answer you'll have to fiddle with it to work. But as long as the short one works, I was glad to help!